# Lossy conversion from float64 to uint8. Range [0, 1]. Convert image to uint8 prior to saving to suppress this warning

Tags: jupyter-notebook, python-3.6

```
pre_dir = '/content/drive/My Drive/preds'
for k in range(len(imgs_mask_test)):
    a=rescale_intensity(imgs_test[k][:,:,0],out_range=(-1,1))
    b=(imgs_mask_test[k][:,:,0]).astype(np.uint8)
    io.imsave(os.path.join(pre_dir, str(k)+'_pre.png'),mark_boundaries(a,b))
```

I want to save multiple images using imsave(). "Lossy conversion from float64 to uint8. Range [0, 1]. Convert image to uint8 prior to saving to suppress this warning." 
Please Help

Answer (score 1):

You can scale first your float64 values in range [0-255] which are the values allowed by uint8 and then convert using numpy. If your images are in range [0-1] you just have to multiply them by 255. Otherwise you have to rescale them and then multiply by 255.

```
uint8image = np.uint8(float64image)
```

Assuming you have numpy arrays to scale the images you can do:

```
Scaled01 = image
Scaled01 -= Scaled01.min()
Scaled01 /= Scaled01.max()
```

Comment: this helped me a lot! Mostly because skimage was showing me a different range than anyone else's. Thank you!